# What is the difference between material-ui and mui

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I'm trying to use a 'Select' component in React. It turns out that there is a version in @material-ui/core and another one in @mui. I'm so confused. Why are there different components out there with different packages? And why is it that Google tells me literally nothing when I ask it this exact question?

Comment: `@material-ui` provides components that follow Google's Material Design system. `@mui` provides components that are "unstyled", These can be used to implement a custom design system that is not based on Material Design.

Comment: I suggest you read yesterday's blog post coinciding with the release of v5 and their rebranding: https://mui.com/blog/mui-core-v5/.

Comment: @tromgy That is not quite correct. All of what used to be within `@material-ui` for v4 has moved to `@mui` for v5. `@mui/material` is the v5 equivalent of v4's `@material-ui/core` and `@mui/core` is where they are putting the "unstyled" components you described.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for clarification. I was writing about `@mui/core` without mentioning it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Material-UI is now MUI. They are rebranding that's all.

https://mui.com/blog/material-ui-is-now-mui/